# Write all strings beginning with a certain substring in a specific range of columns to a new column in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

title, the issue is simple and one i’ve been able to solve with nested loops but i understand those are not preferred in R programming, is there a tidyr way to accomplish this?

i want to iterate over a specific range of columns (here all columns beginning with “DX”) and for each row find if any elements begin with a specific substring (here “A”) and if they do, to write that strong beginning with that substring to a new column (df$As), and if they don’t write NA

here’s the toy data, nested loop solution, and tidyr attempt i’ve been stumped on:

```
# set up data
names <- c("Aidan", "Barry", "Carl")
DX1 <- c("A1", "B1", "C1")
DX2 <- c("C2", "A2", "B2")
DX3 <- c("D3", "C3", "C3")

# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(name = names, DX1 = DX1, DX2 = DX2, DX3 = DX3)

# create a new column filled with NAs, then fill with all DXs beginning with 'A'
df$As <- NA
for(i in 2:4){
  for(j in 1:3){
    if(!is.na(df$As[j])){
      df$As[j] <- df$As[j]
    }else if(grepl("^A", df[j,i])){
      df$As[j] <- df[j,i]
    }else{
      df$As[j] <- NA
    }
  }
}

# tidyr attempt
df2 <- df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("DX"), As = if_else(grepl("^A", .), ., NA)))
```

the tidyr statement throws me an error, i imagine it has to do with how the . is being parsed, i thought i understood it as it going through each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use `across()` and `unite()`. Small drawback is that we need another `mutate` to replace empty strings by `NA`s:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("DX"), ~ if_else(grepl("^A", .x), .x, NA),
      .names = "A{.col}"
    )
  ) |>
  unite(As, starts_with("ADX"), na.rm = TRUE, sep = "") |>
  mutate(As = if_else(As == "", NA, As))
#>    name DX1 DX2 DX3   As
#> 1 Aidan  A1  C2  D3   A1
#> 2 Barry  B1  A2  C3   A2
#> 3  Carl  C1  B2  C3 <NA>
```

Comment: a small price to pay for a much more elegant solution, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

We can define a helper function that uses `purrr::reduce` to find the first match across columns

```
first_match <- function(data, pattern) {
  purrr::reduce(data, function(a, b) {
    coalesce(a, stringr::str_extract(b, "^A.*"))
  }, .init=NA)  
}
```

and then we can apply it to the data.frame

```
df %>% mutate(As = first_match(pick(starts_with("D"))))
```

to get

```
  name  DX1   DX2   DX3   As   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Aidan A1    C2    D3    A1   
2 Barry B1    A2    C3    A2   
3 Carl  C1    B2    C3    NA
```

Alternatively we could also use `rowwise` + `c_across` actions across the columns and find matches using `stringr::str_subset`. I'm not sure of a more efficient way to do this across an entire data.frame at once. This should work

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(As=first(stringr::str_subset(c_across(starts_with("D")), "^A")))
```

Comment: i was considering integrating a function but couldn’t manage it, thanks so much, i really feel like i’ve learned a lot from this answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
    left_join(pivot_longer(.,starts_with('DX'),names_to = NULL, values_to = 'As') %>%
        filter(str_detect(As, '^A')), 'name')
   name DX1 DX2 DX3   As
1 Aidan  A1  C2  D3   A1
2 Barry  B1  A2  C3   A2
3  Carl  C1  B2  C3 <NA>
```

Comment: left join was something else i'd considered, i really appreciate how condensed this solution is too, thank you so much!